# jQuery Tools overlay draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, positioning, draggable, jquery-tools

I have an overlay with the apple effect from jQuery Tools. I want to make it so the overlay is draggable, but when I use `$( ".overlay" ).draggable();` the background image does not drag with it. I tried `appendTo` but it destroyed the apple effect. Also the image for the overlay is rendering outside of the .overlay div.
here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZqNgy/

I am kind of new to jQuery and javascript and would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you do not need 'apple'effect, you can drag background image.
just effect set to 'default'.
and you may be need to change overlay style.

```
example(".overlay").overlay({
    top: 50,
    left: 50,
    closeOnClick: false,
    load: false,
    effect: 'default',
    speed: 1000,
    oneInstance: false,
    fixed: false,
});
```

```
.overlay {
    display:none;
    background-image:url(white.png);
    background-size:cover;
    width:160px;
    padding:20px;
}
```